# Conditional upsert with MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm looking for a way to implement some kind of *if item is not there, insert it; if it's there and it holds a condition, replace it; if it's there and it doesn't fulfill the condition, ignore it*.

I thought about a upsert statement with a pipeline composing a match-stage and a replaceRoot-stage, but match doesn't work with update-pipelines :-(

For example these cases are necessary (while there is an unique index on `title`):

```
Before: {title:'Some cool title', version: 5, value: 'foo', anotherValue: 'val'}
After:  {title:'Some cool title', version: 15, value: 'bar'}

Before: {title:'Some cool title', version: 16, value: 'foo', anotherValue: 'val'}
After:  {title:'Some cool title', version: 16, value: 'foo', anotherValue: 'val'}

Before: <'Some cool title' is missing>
After:  {title:'Some cool title', version: 15, value: 'bar'}
```

Do you know how I can implement this kind of update statement?

Comment: You need to use Updates with Aggregation Pipeline feature (requires MongoDB v4.2 or higher).

Comment: @prasad_: Do you have an example? I already tried with a pipeline consisting of match and replaceRoot and some wierd stuff with a set-stage and $cond for each field of the document but that was rather ugly and the first example kept its `anotherValue`.

Comment: what exactly is the condition? does the object have additional fixed fields that are mandatory?

Comment: @TomSlabbaert In the final statement the condition is a timestamp to prevent overwriting newer data points with older data points which maybe took longer time to reach the system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you specify 3 conditions but from the update perspective it really is only 2.

1. Execute replacement (if doesn't exist this upserts)
2. Don't do anything.

You're approach you tried is the correct approach, I'm assuming you just ran into some syntex issues, here is how to do it:

```
const newData = {title:'Some cool title', version: 15, value: 'bar', timestamp: new Date()}; 

db.collection.updateOne({
  "title": "Some cool title"
},
[
  {
    "$replaceRoot": {
      "newRoot": {
        $cond: [
          {
            $gt: [
              newData.timestamp, 
              "$timestamp"
            ]
          },
          newData, //if newData timestamp is gt the document timestamp ( this is also true if document doesn't exist ) use the newData
          "$$ROOT" // else the condition fails just use the same old root.
        ]
      },
      
    }
  }
],
{
  "upsert": true
})
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/LUY3ZfBRovu)